# HTML table not rendering properly

Tags: html, django, templates

I have a Django view that sends a dictionary whose contents will be rendered in a html page.

My dictionary looks like this,

```
d ={ name : ['damon','stefan','elena'],
      age :  [200,200,25],
      address : ['mystic falls','mystic falls','mystic falls']
      supernatural : ['yes','yes','yes']}
```

Now my html table template looks like this,

```
<table class="table table-striped" border="1" class="dataframe">
    <thead>
     <tr style="text-align: center;">
       {% for i in d %}
       <th>{{ i }}</th>
       {% endfor %}
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     {% for i,j in d.items %}
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
       {% for x in j %}
        <td>{{ x }}</td>
       {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

### problem:

When the rendering completes the dictionaries last values i.e ['yes','yes','yes'] are coming as a row. So below is how the output looks,

```
name     age       address    supernatural
damon    200    mystic falls  
stefan   200    mystic falls  
elena     25    mystic falls  
yes       yes   yes
```

Basically the last columns values are coming as rows.

Can you please help me why is this. Is there something wrong in my html table code above.

Comment: What is width value of table css class?

Comment: you're iterating the column (dictionary keys) instead of the lines (nested array length)

Comment: @Rafael , I have not set any width

Comment: @mirg in the 2nd iteration I am iterating over nested list

Comment: Yes but the previous loop iterate on the keys (which are your columns) and you print rows out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to change your data type. your `d` is a little bit wierd type. I recommend you to change it to normal object (both can familiar in python / javascript object.) like below

```
    d2 = [
        {'name': 'damon', 'age': 200, 'address': 'mystic falls', 'sub': 'yes'},
        {'name': 'stefan', 'age': 200, 'address': 'mystic falls', 'sub': 'yes'},
        {'name': 'elena', 'age': 200, 'address': 'mystic falls', 'sub': 'yes'},
    ]
```

Then you can just forloop in template. like below.

```
<table class="table table-striped" border="1" class="dataframe">
    <thead>
     <tr style="text-align: center;">
       {% for k, v in d2.0.items %}
       <th>{{ k }}</th>
       {% endfor %}
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   {% for x in d2 %}
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
          <td>
              {{ x.name }}
          </td>
          <td>
              {{ x.age }}
          </td>
          <td>
              {{ x.address }}
          </td>
          <td>
              {{ x.sub }}
          </td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
```

ps. you can use your current data, but it's more complicated and really hard to understand - it's hard to matching one person to their data, and even it can't match when some field is blank.

Comment: I followed your method and added the below code,but still getting blank values, <table class="table table-striped" border="1" class="dataframe">
    <thead>
     <tr style="text-align: center;">
       {% for k, v in results.0.items %}
       <th>{{ k }}</th>
       {% endfor %}
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     {% for x in results %}
       <tr style="text-align: center;">
         {% for y in x %}
          <td>
              {{ x.y }}
          </td>
         {% endfor %}
       </tr>
     {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
 </table>

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write the comma " , " after `address:[]`